# How to process data from file -> get data form REST API -> storage in DB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I would like to read data from a file, then query REST APIs with that data, and finally store it all in a database.
I was thinking of using Spring-Batch but don't know how to configure it to make this work.

- Step 1: Read data from file
- Step 2: Make requests on REST APIs
- Step 3: Store in database

For example :
Read the name of a fruit in a file -> Make a request to a REST API to obtain information on this fruit -> Store all the information concerning this fruit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a job with a single chunk-oriented step configured with the following components:

- `FlatFileItemReader` to read the file
- `ItemProcessor` to perform the REST call
- `JdbcBatchItemWriter` to write items to the database

You can find a complete example in the [getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/).